# Upload progress bar in DWR?

Tags: java, javascript, dwr

In my project i want to show the progress bar while uploading files. I am using DWR to get send the data to server, javascript and Java is the server side language. I have done some searches to learn it. But i couldn't able to find one.

Any link to learn or suggestions would be appreciative!!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Progress bar support in DWR right now. Hope, it will be added in their Official DWR 3 release.